# Sorting inside the database or Sorting in code behind? Which is best?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sorting, datatable

I have a dropdown list in my aspx page. Dropdown list's datasource is a datatable. Backend is MySQL and records get to the datatable by using a stored procedure.

I want to display records in the dropdown menu in ascending order.

I can achieve this by two ways.

1) dt is datatable and I am using dataview to filter records.

```
dt = objTest_BLL.Get_Names();

dataView = dt.DefaultView; 
dataView.Sort = "name ASC";
dt = dataView.ToTable();

ddown.DataSource = dt;
ddown.DataTextField = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
ddown.DataValueField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
ddown.DataBind();
```

2) Or in the select query I can simply say that

```
SELECT
`id`,
`name`
FROM `test`.`type_names`
ORDER BY `name` ASC ;
```

If I use 2nd method I can simply eliminate the dataview part. Assume this type_names table has 50 records. And my page is view by 100,000 users at a minute. What is the best method by considering efficiency,Memory handling? Get unsorted records to datatable and filter in code behind or sort them inside the datatabse?

Comment: If you have 100,000 users a minute, you should really cache the data and not load it every time from the db.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note - Only real performance tests can tell you real numbers.. Theoretical options are below (which is why I use word guess a lot in this answer).
You have at least 3 (instead of 2) options -

1. Sort in database - If the column being sorted on is indexed.. Then this may make most sense, because overhead of sorting on your database server may be negligible. SQL servers own data caches may make this super fast operation.. but 100k queries per minute.. measure if SQL gives noticeably faster results without sort.
2. Sort in code behind / middle layer - Likely you won't have your own equivalent of index.. you'd be sorting list of 50 records, 100k times per minutes.. would be slower than SQL, I would guess.
   Big benefit would apply, only if data is relatively static, or very slow changing, and sorted values can be cached in memory for few seconds to minutes or hours..
3. The option not in your list - send the data unsorted all the way to the client, and sort it on client side using javascript. This solution may scale the most... sorting 50 records in Browser, should not be a noticeable impact on your UX.

Comment: Nice ideas Vikas. I will wait little bit and decide which answer is suit me. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The SQL purists will no doubt tell you that it’s better to let SQL do the sorting rather than C#. That said, unless you are dealing with massive record sets or doing many queries per second it’s unlikely you’d notice any real difference.

For my own projects, these days I tend to do the sorting on C# unless I’m running some sort of aggregate on the statement. The reason is that it’s quick, and if you are running any sort of stored proc or function on the SQL server it means you don’t need to find ways of passing order by’s into the stored proc.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply harvyk. What you mean by "if you are running any sort of stored proc or function on the SQL server it means you don’t need to find ways of passing order by’s into the stored proc." ? Please explain it.

Comment: Typically stored procedures have "hard coded" into them the full SELECT statement, including which columns will be returned, FROM which tables and the ORDER BY. The WHERE is pretty much the only part which will use arguments which the stored proc was called using. ORDER BY typically requires columns defined at design time.

You can build the SQL into a string (varchar) and then execute that string. In that case you can pass in what ever combination of order by columns you'd like. That said doing that opens you up to a world of SQL Injection pain.

Comment: You can also add: It is a lot easier to scale the front end / web level (and cheaper). The database is more expensive to scale. Taking load of the database in large scale scenarios can make a real difference. Not that it matters for most cases.

Comment: I was in a performance tuning class with Brent Ozar a few years ago and Brent mentioned that sorting operations on the database is usually more expensive and that omitting the ORDER BY and instead sorting in your data layer is usually better. We're doing ASP.NET so we changed our data layer to omit the ORDER BY and instead we sort the data in an ADO.NET DataTable and then bind that DataTable to our UI object (such as a gridview).